# Spring boot not redirecting after validate

Tags: spring

I've been reading much about the subject but I can't understand it at all.

I have just started to build a web project from 0 with Spring Boot and Java and I have access to static files (css and js place on their respective folders in /resources/static/) but when from the jsp view I validate a login-form my Controller does not catch the PostMapping action.

I realized that my Controller works fine when I set up from application.properties the

```
spring.resources.add-mappings : false
```

but I stop seeing my static resources.

I want of course to fix it, understand it and prepare the environment to go making it bigger.

### Edited

Yes, my css and js files are under /resources/static

Right now, I have a Controller with a GetMapping("/home") and a PostMapping("/home") methods. When I launch the project and access through localhost:8080/home the flow gets in the GetMapping method and it simply shows a jsp view. To do that I had to add these two lines into application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Also I have there:

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true
spring.resources.add-mappings: true
```

Here is just a login page, when submit, the PostMapping does not handle the petition and anything happens

To fix it I can change

```
spring.resources.add-mappings: false
```

and it works but then, crazy to understand to me, I have no access to js and css files

I have no MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer not any similar.

Comment: How did you create your project ? using SpringInitializr?

Comment: No, by Eclipse. File -> New Project -> Spring Boot, Spring Starter Project. Shoul I have used the other way?

Comment: @trivli Is your static resources under src/main/resources ? What is the problem you are facing actually ?

Comment: @MebinJoe I answer you editing the original

Comment: Did you check the Spring Boot reference docs?
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content
By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a folder called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext.

You can also compare your project with the source code of the spring-boot-sample-web-ui project.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Comment: worst case try spring.resources.static-locations=file:/static,classpath:static